# Use same Airflow task in multiple branch

Tags: python, airflow, task

Is there way I can re-use airflow task that needs to be executed in each branch execution.

for ex. I have below tasks out of each task_1 and task_2 needs to be run in 1st flow and task_3 in 2nd flow but task_comm needs to be run in both cases. How can i create 1 task and call it in both flow ?

```
flow_1 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'flow_1')
task_1 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_1')
task_2 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_2')

flow_2 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'flow_2')
task_3 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_3')

task_comm = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_comm')

branch >> flow_1 >> task_1 >> task2 >> task_comm
branch >> flow_2 >> task_3 >> task_comm
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have two different branches, one of them will be succeeded and the second will be skipped. To run the `task_comm` after any one of them, you just need to update its trigger rule:

```py
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
task_comm = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_comm', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED)
```

In this case, `task_comm` will be executed when the tasks [`task2`, `task_3`] have one of the states [`succeeded`, `skipped`]. In your case, one of them will have `succeeded` and the second will have `skipped`, which is enough to trigger the task.

Comment: @Hussien
Can I use same task in multiple branch of a dag ? or do i need to rename the task in each of branch 

for ex . 

`flow_1 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'flow_1') 
task_1 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_1') 
task_2 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_2') 

flow_2 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'flow_2') 
task_2 = DummyOperator(task_id = 'task_2') 

branch >> flow_1 >> task_1 >> task2 
branch >> flow_2`

when I check the above dag in Graph view I see both branch are connected and if create new task and use it flow_2 it looks correct